# Pytorch version on g5.xlarge

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I would like to run a g5.xlarge on AWS with pytorch.
However I have this error when I try to do something with cuda in python (for example `torch(1., device="cuda")`):

```
The current PyTorch install supports CUDA capabilities sm_37 sm_50 sm_60 sm_70.
If you want to use the NVIDIA A10G GPU with PyTorch, please check the instructions at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
```

Here's the `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.82.00    Driver Version: 470.82.00    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A10G         Off  | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
|  0%   25C    P0    55W / 300W |   1815MiB / 22731MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     10415      C   /miniconda3/bin/python           1813MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any idea? Which version of CUDA/pytorch should I use ?

Comment: One with compiled in support for the Ampere architecture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The A10G GPU uses `sm_86` which is natively supported in `CUDA>=11.1`.

The PyTorch website provides a very handy [tool](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) to find the right install command for any required OS / PyTorch / CUDA configuration:
[image]

For the AWS g5.xlarge instances with A10G GPUs the following configuration works for me:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 3.8.5
- PyTorch 1.12.1
- CUDA 11.6

**Conda install command:**

`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.6 -c pytorch -c conda-forge`

**Pip install command:**

`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this thread discussion thread [pytorch-cuda-arch issue](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/need-help-trouble-with-cuda-capability-sm-86/120235/12). The issue seems similar.